# Как отсортировать элементы массива по значениям одинаковых ключей?

Tags: php, массивы

У меня есть большой массив (список постов из ВК, полученный через API), по которому разбросаны ключи `date`, содержащие UNIX-дату. Мне нужно отсортировать массив по возрастанию значения `date`. Как это сделать?

[вот вывод массива через print_r](http://pastebin.com/P7eJ8FDy)

Comment: Сортировка по ключу по убыванию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.krsort.php

Comment: Добавьте пример набора данных

Comment: Хм, а как в массиве могут быть одинаковые ключи у двух разных элементов? О_о

Comment: @Visman да, только что проверил - у меня куча ключей `date` с разными значениями

Comment: @Visman ой, мне по возрастанию нужно, ошибся (вопрос уже исправил). Попробовал ksort() - тоже как-то странно сортирует - самое новое кидает ниже более старых вещей.

Comment: Массив/часть массива в вопросе покажите как Umed просил. А то гадание на кофейной гуще только.

Comment: @Visman добавил ссылку в вопрос

Comment: Весь код, относящийся к вопросы, должен быт в _самом вопросе_. Ссылки могут служить _только дополнением_

Comment: @DmitriySimushev а вы посмотрите сколько там кода.

Comment: Значит вы должны подготовить _минимальный_ пример, описывающий вашу проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Надо воспользоваться `usort`:

```
function cmp($a,$b) {
  return ($a['date'] > $b['date']) ? 1 : 0;
}

$arr = ...; //ответ от вк
$arr = array_shift($arr);

usort($arr,"cmp");
```

Функции `usort` необходимо передавать свою функцию сравнения элементов, в нашем случае `cmp`.

**UPD:** прочитал *сортировать по убыванию*, исправил

Comment: Что-то у меня оно вообще как-то рандомно сортирует.

Comment: @DeFF, оно сортировало по убыванию, я как-то не так понял пост сразу. Поправил, теперь сортирует по возрастанию.

Comment: @DeFF, Если Вы скинете пример Вашего списка постов, то я поправлю под него, а то непонятно с чем работаем)

Comment: [вот пример json, который я получаю по API ВК](https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-1&count=10) и [вот вывод массива через print_r](http://pastebin.com/P7eJ8FDy)

Comment: @DeFF, попробуйте так

Comment: `Notice: Use of undefined constant cmp - assumed 'cmp' in D:\home\site\wwwroot\feed.php on line 36 Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in D:\home\site\wwwroot\feed.php on line 36 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\home\site\wwwroot\feed.php on line 39`

Comment: @DeFF, исправьте вызов с `usort($arr,cmp);` на `usort($arr,"cmp");`

Comment: `Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given`